# Creating a BAT file for Net User Command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying create a bat file to check net user command.

Basically I want it to say something like

```
Please enter username: 
net user %username% /Domain
```

When entering the username I want that to be entered into the %username% section. I have created a few tests but as I say I am pretty new to this. Also please explain what each bit is doing as this will help me learn.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." You also must provide your question **as text**, not as images.

Comment: `set` is the command you're looking for. Type `set /?` and read it's output. Note the parameter `/p`

Comment: [This link](http://ss64.com/nt/net-useradmin.html) can help you for the `net user` part

Comment: `USERNAME` is an environment variable predefined by Windows. Open a command prompt window and run `set` to see the list of predefined environment variables and read Wikipedia article about [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows). Use in your batch file a different name for the environment variable like `NameOfUser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off what you asked, I am taking it that you want to make a batch application that asks for your username, and adds that to a domain using the net user command. This can be done by doing the following:

```
echo off
goto :input
cls

:input
cls
echo Enter Username to be added:
echo[
set /p username=
net user %username% /domain
goto :input
cls
```

Hopefully that answers your question! But next time, please be more specific on the task you want to achieve. The people who read this should be able to know what you want done without having to question "Is this what the person wants?" or second guess themselves. Makes answering easier.

Comment: Hello,

Your script was the perfect base but unfortunately it clear the moment it was ran. I have now got it down to:

@echo off
goto :input
cls

:input
echo Enter Username to be added:
echo[
set /p username=
net user %username% /domain
goto input

Thank you once again for your Help